# Can Spring set datasource from service discovery?

Tags: spring, microservices, spring-cloud, consul, service-discovery

Before I start trying to programmatically set datasource configuration in my app using service discovery, I would like to be sure this functionality is not already managed by Spring.

In my case I am using Consul as the discovery service. So I read http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/1.0.x/index.html but don't really find something to answer my question (prolly because of my flawed knowledge of Spring configuration itself).

Basically I would configure the discovery system in a `bootstrap.yml` file

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: localhost
      port: 8500
```

then in the `application.yml` I would set something like:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:${consul.service.datasource}
```

Is this possible "natively". If not, what do I miss in the concepts involved?

Comment: It should. Have you tried? If so, what were the results?